# Styling outputted code from a database. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, styles, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to style my code that is being pulled out from the database. It is multi-lined code stored as a VAR-CHAR on a table "table1".

```
echo "<section class='styleElement'>" . htmlentities($code_display['Code']) . "</section>";
```

It displays the code fine, but it just places it all in a big block of text.

What I am asking is:

How do I indent each part correctly, and list all the elements so that it looks like a readable page.

The example: [My page im working on](http://hatsy.net/new/portview.php?portID=11&portCat=Codes)

Any help would be appreciated. I have looked around, but most answers I find are more about the (htmlspecialchars / htmlentities).

I am not too bothered by colour coding the elements on the page, just the indentations, and numbering.

I am exploring the explode function at the moment, so I should now be ok.

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format your output, use `<pre>` or `nl2br()`.

Comment: Thanks, i found the main issue with my code was that I was inputting directly into the database through the phpmyadmin page. When i inputted the code via a textarea element it registered the codes shape and format, and then put it inside <pre> elements to get it working. Thanks for the help. Im slowly getting their with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this [PEAR class](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/redirected). It allows you to programmatically format PHP code.